# F# custom computation workflow

Tags: f#, monads, monad-transformers

Given the result type

```
type Result<'t> = OK of 't | Error of string
```

I have these functions which all return Async < Result<'t> > which are combined something like this:

```
let a = async { return Result.OK 1000 }
let b = async { return Result.Error "some message" }

let sum x y = 
    async {
        let! r1 = x
        match r1 with
        | Result.OK v1 -> 
             let! r2 = y
             match r2 with
             | Result.OK v2 -> return v1 + v2
             | Result.Error msg -> return Result.Error msg
        | Result.Error msg -> return Result.Error msg
    }
```

This code looks bad so instead I would like to have this:

```
type Result = Ok of int | Error of string

type MyMonadBuilder() =
    member x.Bind (v,f) = 
        async { 
            let! r = v
            match r with
            | Ok r' -> return! f r'
            | Error msg -> return Error msg
        }

    member x.Return v = async {return Ok v }

    member x.Delay(f) = f()

let mymonad = MyMonadBuilder()
let runMyMonad = Async.RunSynchronously

let a = mymonad { return 10 }
let b = mymonad { return 20 }

let c = 
    mymonad { 
        return Result.Error "Some message"
        //??? The above doesn't work but how do I return a failure here?
    }

let d = 
    async {
        return Ok 1000
    } 
    //how to wrap this async with mymonad such that I can use it together with my other computation expressions?

let sum x y = 
    mymonad {
        let! v1 = x
        let! v2 = y
        return v1 + v2
    }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let v = sum a b |> runMyMonad
    match v with
    | Ok v' -> printfn "Ok: %A" v'
    | Error msg -> printf "Error: %s" msg

    System.Console.Read() |> ignore
    0
```

So the questions are:

1. How do I write function c such that it returns an error in mymonad?
2. How do I write function d such that it wraps an async with a mymonad?
3. How can I make my monad parameterized in a similar way Async is?

...such that I can write

```
let f (a:MyMonad<int>) (b:MyMonad<string>) = ...
```

UPDATE:

Also I would like to run several mymonad operations in parallel and then look at the array of results to see what were the errors and the successes. For this reason I think using exceptions is not a good idea.

Also, regarding the question 3, what I meant was to have my type parameterized and opaque such that the callers don't know/don't care they are dealing with an async. The way I wrote the monad the caller can always use Async.RunSynchronously to run a mymonad expression.

UPDATE 2:

So far I ended up with the following:

1. I use an explicit type for each member of MyMonadBuilder
2. I added ReturnFrom to the MyMonadBuilder. I use this function to wrap an Async< Result<'t> >
3. I added helper functions like failwith which create a mymonad with the error value

The code looks like this:

```
type MyMonad<'t> = 't Result Async

type MyMonadBuilder() =
    member x.Bind<'t> (v,f) : MyMonad<'t>= 
        async { 
            let! r = v
            match r with
            | Ok r' -> return! f r'
            | Error msg -> return Error msg
        }

    member x.Return<'t> v  : MyMonad<'t> = async {return Ok v }
    member x.ReturnFrom<'t> v  : MyMonad<'t> = v

    member x.Delay(f) = f()

let failwith<'t> : string -> MyMonad<'t> = Result.Error >> async.Return
```

This looks reasonably good for my purpose. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`asyncChoice`](https://github.com/jack-pappas/ExtCore/blob/master/ExtCore/Control.fs#L1448) workflow from my [ExtCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ExtCore/) library already implements this -- it's available on NuGet so all you need to do is add a reference to your project, open the `ExtCore.Control` namespace in your source files, and start writing code like this:

```
open ExtCore.Control

let asyncDivide100By (x : int) =
    asyncChoice {
        if x = 0 then
            return! AsyncChoice.error "Cannot divide by zero."
        else
            return (100 / x)
    }

let divide100By (x : int) =
    let result =
        asyncDivide100By x
        |> Async.RunSynchronously

    match result with
    | Choice1Of2 result ->
        printfn "100 / %i = %i" x result
    | Choice2Of2 errorMsg ->
        printfn "An error occurred: %s" errorMsg


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    divide100By 10
    divide100By 1
    divide100By 0

    0   // Exit code
```

asyncChoice is constructed using the standard `Async<'T>` and `Choice<_,_>` types from the F# Core library, so you shouldn't have any compatibility problems.

Comment: I don't think using Choice extensively produces readable code. I seem to be unable to remember what Choice1 and Choice2 mean. So if the result type is used in the whole library I think it's better to have a custom type defined. Also besides Ok and Error there might be other Result constructors as well (ex: Canceled). On the other hand I will look at your code as there are some good examples and the code looks clean and readable. Thanks

Comment: I mark this as the accepted answer because the code in Extcore provided guidance to understand what I need to do. Thanks!

Comment: @vidi ExtCore also provides an active pattern `(|Success|Error|)` for convenience when you're working with `Choice<_,_>` values. It's inlined so there isn't any run-time performance penalty in using it.

Comment: Still incomplete documentation though :\

Answer (score 4):

Asynchronous workflows automatically support error handling through exceptions, so the idiomatic solution is to just use exceptions. If you want to distinguish some special kind of errors, then you can just define a custom exception type:

```
exception MyError of string

// Workflow succeeds and returns 1000
let a = async { return 1000 }
// Workflow throws 'MyError' exception
// (using return! means that it can be treated as a workflow returning int)
let b = async { return! raise (MyError "some message") }

// Exceptions are automatically propagated
let sum = async {
  let! r1 = a
  let! r2 = b
  return r1 + r2 }
```

If you want to handle exceptions, you can use `try ... with MyError msg -> ...` inside an asynchronous workflow.

You *could* define a custom computation builder that re-implements this using an algebraic data type such as your `Result`, but unless you have some really good reason for doing that, I would not recommend this approach - it will not work with standard libraries, it is quite complicated and does not fit with the general F# style.

In your computation expression, the type of values is `Async<Result<'T>>`, `return` automatically wraps the argument of type `'T` in an async workflow that returns `Ok`. If you wanted to construct a value representing a failure, you can use `return!` and create an async workflow that returns `Result.Error`. You probably need something like this:

```
let c = mymonad { 
  return! async.Return(Result.Error "Some message")
}
let d = mymonad {
    return 1000
}
```

But as I said, using exceptions is a better approach.

**EDIT:** To answer the question in the comments - if you have a number of async computations, you can still wrap the final result in your custom type. However, you do not need to rebuild the entire asynchronous workflow library - errors in the primitive operations can still be handled using standard exceptions:

```
// Primitive async work that may throw an exception
let primitiveAsyncWork = async { ... } 

// A wrapped computation that returns standard Option type
let safeWork = async {
  try 
    let! res = primitiveAsyncWork
    return Some res
  with e -> return None }

// Run 10 instances of safeWork in parallel and filter out failed computations
async { let! results = [ for i in 0 .. 9 -> safeWork ] |> Async.Parallel
        return results |> Seq.choose id }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand your point regarding the usage of exceptions. My problem is that I want to run many of these mymonad operations in parallel. Some of them might fail, some of them might succeed. At the end I want to see the array of results and filter the errors or the successes. For this reason using Result is better then using exceptions as it is more "parallelism friendly".

Comment: @vidi You do not need to define a custom workflow for this though. It is perfectly sufficient to wrap computation in `try .. with` and return `Ok res` in the main body and `Error ex` in the exception handler.

Comment: Suppose I want to run several computations in parallel. This gives me a list of results. Then for each item in the list, based on the result type (i.e. OK | Error etc), some of them I retry - it depends. The retry decision is taken in an upper layer and I don't want the low-level async computation itself to know when it should retry. If I implement this based on exceptions and one of the computation in the list fails then the whole composed computation fails which is not what I want

Comment: @vidi I added an example that shows this to the answer. I think it is pretty simple and straightforward - you could wrap that functionality in some reusable function and it would certainly be cleaner than using custom workflow...

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is that if you choose to define your own custom workflow (or even use CoreExt `asyncChoice`) then most of the standard functions will not be directly usable - you'll have to write wrappers for everything.

Comment: This looks nice. I'll think about using your approach. Thanks!

Comment: @vidi Thanks! I guess I should have posted this example in the first place (I guess it was difficult to see what I meant initially.)

Comment: @TomasPetricek ExtCore provides re-implementations of many (most?) of the important standard functions for each of the workflows it exposes; all you need to do is prefix the workflow name. For example, if you're using `asyncChoice` and you want to use `List.mapi`, you would just call [`AsyncChoice.List.mapi`](https://github.com/jack-pappas/ExtCore/blob/master/ExtCore/ControlCollections.AsyncChoice.fs#L414) instead. The OP would only need to provide custom wrappers for any one-off functions specific to his application.

Comment: @JackP. Yes, using `asyncChoice` (with all the functions already available) is certainly an option - way better than implementing custom computation based on the OP's type. I guess I would still use standard `async` here, because the task is quite simple.

Comment: @JackP. Additional functions in ExtCore are certainly useful :-) but if you had `Async.List.map` that would propagate exceptions correctly too. (I'm not a big fan of re-implementing language features in a more functional way, just for the sake of it - but I see that `asyncChoice` might still be useful, e.g. for performance if you had too many exceptions).

Comment: @TomasPetricek I agree, in general it's best not to re-implement language features without a good reason. I see `asyncChoice` being useful in scenarios when you need to return some data along with the error; you could also do this by deriving your own type(s) from `Exception`, but then you need to remember to check everywhere for that specific exception type in your `with` blocks. With `choice` or `asyncChoice`, the errors propagate similarly but the type inference can do more to keep you safe.

Comment: @TomasPetricek And ExtCore does have [`Async.List.map`](https://github.com/jack-pappas/ExtCore/blob/master/ExtCore/ControlCollections.Async.fs#L582) too :)

Comment: @JackP. Yes, I completely agree - the scenario with returning data, together with exceptions (and propagating that) makes very good sense.